# class object referred by class loader?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, classloader

why class objects are referred by class loader ? should it not be other way around i.e. class loader should have been referred
so that class object could have become eligible for GC if class object is unreachable and lesser memory consumption ?

I know i am missing some thing basic here but not sure what. I tried googling it but could not find answered

Comment: class loader is part of JVM which actually store the details about class structure in memory like fields methods etc for system and a newly created object is a mirror copy of that class structure in the memory on which you actually perform your operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `ClassLoader` loads classes and its responsibility is to know what classes it has loaded. `Class` objects *also* have a reference to the `ClassLoader` that loaded it, hence the [getClassLoader()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--) method in `Class`.

Memory consumption has **absolutely nothing** to do with anything here, I can't imagine why you would think it does.

Comment: Ok let me put in another way. Should it not be responsibility of only class object to know who loaded it(as you said it already does that i.e.Class objects also have a reference to the ClassLoader that loaded it). If it was, then unreachable class object could have been GC'd when unreachable(becoz at present even if class object is unreachable its not GC'd because its referred by class loader) ?

Comment: No, it should not. Class unloading is not very important at least from a memory point of view. However a `ClassLoader` knowing which classes it has loaded is very important, so it doesn't load the same class twice for example. You're very obsessed about GCing classes. Don't worry, it's possible and easy even in the current situation.

Comment: @Kayaman while it's indeed necessary for a ClassLoader to know, which Classes were already loaded, it does not mean that class loaders maintain references to these classes.

Comment: If you would look at source code of java.lang.ClassLoader in Oracle JDK, you would find that this functionality is delegated to JVM via native call. JVM is maintaining its own registry of Class objects and their bindings to class loaders. JVM spec btw does not have any specific requirements to the implementation regarding the references to loaded classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html

Answer (score 0):

If you look at implementation of class java.lang.ClassLoader, you will find that actual instantiation of Class objects happens "behind the scenes" by JVM. Class information is obtained by native methods (e.g. findLoadedClass0) and ClassLoader invokes native method defineClass1 to define new class when necessary. How these methods are implemented depends on JVM.

Thus, it's not necessary to maintain these references for the purposes of object instantiation. However, as states comment to the Vector of Class objects in the source code of java.lang.ClassLoader:

```
// The classes loaded by this class loader. The only purpose of this table
// is to keep the classes from being GC'ed until the loader is GC'ed.
// private final Vector<Class<?>> classes = new Vector<>();
```

The consequence is that if you need to free memory of unused Class definitions, you need to GC the ClassLoader itself. It's possible if there's no object containing a reference to any of the classes loaded by that class loader and you can just forget the reference to that class loader. This is exactly what's happening in JEE application servers and OSGi containers when they unload web applications and plugins.

Comment: You're right that it's not something we should care about, but your first sentence isn't [absolutely true](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ClassLoader.java#180).

Comment: Thanks, I've didn't notice that.